# How to refresh all clients JS files without "?v=xxx"

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I have a CMS based application, where each part of system uses JS file (form_X.js, details_X.js,..). These files are cached so any change isn't obvious for one hour or until refreshing URL of that file. I need a special page, where all files will be loaded and refreshed.

```
var versionUpdate = (new Date()).getTime();
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "/components/com_fabrik/js/form_3.js?v=" + versionUpdate;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

but it only loaded fresh form_3.js on this new page. Page that loads implicitly only "form_3.js" (without ?v=....) keeps loading old version. Cache somehow doesn't recognize that they are same files and won't refresh old form_3.js

I don't want to add version parameter to all loaded files due to performance. Any ideas

Comment: Is it really SO bad for performance to add the version or date after the url?

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: If you cannot perfect your [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (cache-control, expires) it is reasonable to include your version to the file URL. It makes sure the correct version is loaded, what could be better than that? Perfecting the HTTP headers needed is certainly more work.

Comment: change it to form4.js and problem fixed :D or tell the user that has that problem to hit "CTRL + F5" on keyboard to refresh it correctly

Comment: Thanks for all comments. I added ? . date("Ymd") to refresh at least once a day. However, could there be problem since you load every day js file, each time its saved to cache, could there be performance issue (after X months you will have hundreds of files cached)